# How to use a DropDown to load and open files?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method in my BusinessLayer. The result of this method is a variable of type `IEnumerable<string>` and is returning me a list of filenames that are matching a description. How can I make all these files to be displayed in WinForms DropDown, and then when I click on a file name to open it?

Here is the method for locating the files:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFilesByInfSite()
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path...").
                Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
    return files;
}
```

If necessary I can show the code for Deserialization.

Comment: Well, don't use Path.GetFileName() since that won't let you find that file back.  Use ToList() and *then* GetFileName() to add items to a  ComboBox.  Then an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged to pick the path name back up from that list.

Comment: Assign the return value from that method to the `DataSource` property of the combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to make your ComboBox store both the filename (to be displayed to the user) and the full path (for you to use). This can be achieved in different ways, here's one of them:

- Change the return type of your `GetFilesByInfSite()` method to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.
- Make it create *and return* a list that contains the filename *as the key* and the path *as the value*.
- Use this list as the DataSource of the ComboBox.
- Whenever the index of the ComboBox changes, retrieve the file path *using the [`SelectedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue) property* and use that to open the file.

**The method would look something like this:**

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetFilesByInfSite()
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path...")
        .Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Path.GetFileName(f), f))
        .ToList(); 

    return files;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> files = GetFilesByInfSite();
files.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("[Select a file]", null));
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(files, null);
```

**And then in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ComboBox, you can do this:**

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) return;

    // Use `filePath` to do whatever you want:
    MessageBox.Show(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Note: If how to open the file is part of your question as well, please explain exactly what you mean by "open".